# Best back-end choice for GPS-tracking application

Tags: android, ios, mobile, gps, backend

I'm about to create a GPS-tracking application for pizza-delivery services in my city, so that when someone orders pizza over the phone or Internet, he can see the courier that carries pizza to him on the map.

Assuming that both courier and client use Android- or iOS-based phone for transmitting/receiving current position, how can I organize a reliable connection between them? Should the courier's phone send his coordinates to my server via HTTP every 5 seconds for delivering it to client, or it will be better to set up something like p2p connection?

I don't know where to start, please help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Other services use server type implementation.  Not sure how would you do it for p2p.

Answer (score 1):

There are open source solutions for GPS tracking. You can start from there instead of developing everything from scratch.

Traccar server (back-end for receiving location data from various devices):

- https://github.com/tananaev/traccar

There are also apps for Android and iOS, but only for transmitting location data:

- https://github.com/tananaev/traccar-client-android
- https://github.com/tananaev/traccar-client-ios

Answer (score 0):

I don't think p2p will be a good solution.

Most of the application use web services and make server calls after a definite interval of time like 10 seconds or 15 seconds refresh to get updated data on both side of apps(Client and courier).

If you want to build a real time application like other real time apps then you need to implement sockets on web and on mobile apps.

But I think in your case web services would be good enough solution.